# Selecting child of adjacent sibling

Tags: css, css-selectors, selector

For markup such as:

```
<span class="location-title-container">
</span>

<div class="content-panel">
    <div class="floor-left-panel"></div>
    <div class="floor-right-panel"></div>
</div>
```

How do I select `.floor-left-panel` when hovering over `.location-title-container`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a adjacent selector to get the element right after it.
Your selector would look like this:

```
.location-title-container:hover + .content-panel .floor-left-panel { … }
```

Just for your information, you should not use `:hover` on `span` tags.
They are not accessible by default. You should add some WAI ARIA role tags.

Comment: Thank you for informing me about the implications to accessibility!

Answer (score 1):

`.location-title-container:hover + .content-panel .floor-left-panel {}` is the selector you need.

The plus sign is used to select the next adjacent element in the DOM.